# sqlitecipher & std::function incompatibility

Tags: c++, sqlite, c++11, encryption, sqlcipher

I use **sqlitecipher** (https://github.com/devbean/QtCipherSqlitePlugin) as Qt plugin to encrypt/decrypt my sqlite database. OS is **Ubuntu 14.04**, compiler is **GCC 4.9**, **Qt** version is **5.5.1**.

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <functional>
#include <QtSql>

struct A
{
    template<typename R>
    R fun(std::function<R(double&)> const& f);
    double db;
};

template<typename R>
R A::fun(std::function<R(double&)> const& f)
{
    return f(db);
}

template<>
void A::fun<void>(std::function<void(double&)> const& f)
{
    f(db);
}

double fun(std::function<double(double)> f)
{
    return f(1.1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A a;
    a.fun<double>([](double&)->double{return 0;});

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLCIPHER", "db");
    db.setDatabaseName(db_path); // encrypted database
    db.open();
    QSqlQuery q(db);                
    q.exec("pragma key='testkey'"); 
    bool res =  q.exec("SELECT * FROM TestTable LIMIT 10"); // res == false

    while (q.next()) {
      qDebug() << q.value(0);
    }

    db.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I can't decrypt my database, if i use `std::function` in the **template functions** (`res == false`).
If use `db.setPassword("testkey")` instead of `q.exec("pragma key='testkey'");`, i have *segmentation fault*.

When I remove the specialization of templates and the template or replace `std::function` with a pointer to a function, decryption works.

What is special about this situation?

***The presence of the template and its specialization kills decryption after compilation. Even without the explicit use.***

Comment: I don't see in the code where you're using the `a` or the function it references.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious  the presence of the template and its specialization kills decryption after compilation. Even without the explicit use

Comment: I think it is a feature of the compiler. Using visual studio does not reproduce this error

Comment: Sounds like you have undefined behavior somewhere in your code. Step through it with a debugger to find out where and why it's faulting.

Comment: I wonder whether the outcome changes if `A`'s constructor initializes `A::db` to some valid value.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, seg fault was in `int sqlite3OsShmLock(sqlite3_file *id, int, int, int);` function (http://web.mit.edu/freebsd/head/contrib/sqlite3/sqlite3.c)